# Сделать выбор устройства вывода звука из программы WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, аудио, visual-studio-2017, naudio

Как можно реализовать выбор устройства вывода звука из программы WPF С#?
В принципе не знаю как это реализовать. Хочу в программу Vidyo.io для ПК(WPF C#) реализовать такой функционал.

Comment: А если не WPF, знаете как сделать?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. У вас уже есть какой-то код для воспроизведения и вам к нему нужно прикрутить выбор устройства? Если да, то покажите код воспроизведения.

Comment: Нет, в принципе как сделать не знаю. У меня программа Vidyo.io WPF C#. Программа для видео звонков. Хочу в ней сделать выбор устройства.

Comment: Сам проект [Naudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) содержит примеры как работать с этой библиотекой, например `NAudioWpfDemo` и там, если мне память не изменяет, есть пример кода как выводить доступные аудиоустройства и выбирать между ними.